# Check file against multiple extensions?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm wondering if it is possible to check if a file matches a list of set extention. at the moment i have a working code that only checks a file to see if it has a .txt .jpg or .mp3

***Example***

```
If (Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() = ".txt") Then
                ' It's a .txt file
                '         MsgBox("I am a Txt Document")
                b.Image = My.Resources.Text_Img

            ElseIf (Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() = ".jpg") Then
                b.Image = My.Resources.Img_Img
            Else
                b.Image = My.Resources.Folder_Img
            End If
```

This code simply set the image for the Shortcut. I want to be able to check if a file matches more than a txt but a .doc .log 
then all video types mp4 avi mpg.
then all Audio types mp3 ogg flacc acc

***Tried, But Failed***

```
ElseIf (Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() = ".jpg"  & ".png" & ".jpeg" & ".tiff") Then
    b.Image = My.Resources.Img_Img
End If
```

is this possible don't want to add all 100+ extension to each have their own If Statements.
Thank you in advanced. 
-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the dictionary route (for no real good reason, other than this being an alternative method), you can use an in-line array to check for each group of extensions.

```
Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower

If {".txt"}.Contains(extension) Then
    b.Image = My.Resources.Text_Img
ElseIf {".jpg", ".png", ".tif"}.Contains(extension) Then
    b.Image = My.Resources.Img_Img
Else
    b.Image = My.Resources.Folder_Img
End If
```

I'm sure there are perfectly valid and aesthetically pleasing methods using RegEx and all sorts of LINQ or other weird ways of doing it!

Comment: it could also be a static array of arrays where (1) holds the list of extensions and (0) holds the corresponding type (Video. image, text, doc, shortcut, html ...).  A dictionary makes more sense if the extensions list is used in other places or other ways, but not if this is the only place.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an If you could look up the code from a dictionary of values. Declare the dictionary as:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, TheResourceType)
dictionary.Add(".txt", My.Resources.Text_Img)
dictionary.Add(".jpg", My.Resources.Img_Img)
dictionary.Add(".png", My.Resources.Img_Img)
dictionary.Add(".jpeg", My.Resources.Img_Img)
dictionary.Add(".tiff", My.Resources.Img_Img)
```

The question is not clear about the type of `b.Image` or the `My.Resources...` values, so change `TheResourceType` as needed.

Access the values with code like:

```
Dim ext As Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()
If dictionary.ContainsKey(ext) Then
    b.Image = dictionary.Item(ext)
Else
    b.Image = My.Resources.Folder_Img
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that:

```
Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()

If extension.Equals("txt") Then
    b.Image = My.Resources.Text_Img
ElseIf extension.Equals("jpg") OrElse extension.Equals("png") OrElse extension.Equals("tif") Then
    b.Image = My.Resources.Img_Img
Else
    b.Image = My.Resources.Folder_Img
End If
```

In above code Path.GetExtension() method is called only once, instead of every time the extension is checked. Second, it uses string build-in Equals() method to check extensions. Third, syntax of the check against multiple extensions is fixed - look at the second condition regarding the image files - it is slightly different than yours.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already considered this, but another option (if this is a common need) would be to create a database table of common extensions and then write a function to query that table, passing in Path.GetExtension as a parameter.

An exhaustive list of extensions for such database table can be found here: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html